# object property name as variable

Tags: javascript

I have this code below and I'm trying to make the property name "`color`" in the "`maps.setColors({`" replaced with its value from the drivers array:

```
var drivers = {
    "drivers":[
       {
          "driver_id":"101",
          "driver_name":"B",
          "truck_capacity":1000,
          "truck_color":"#00FF00",
          "truck_radio":"checked"
       },
       {
          "driver_id":"102",
          "driver_name":"A",
          "truck_capacity":2000,
          "truck_color":"#FF0000",
          "truck_radio":""
       }
     ]
 };

for (var prop in drivers) { 
        if (drivers.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { 
            for (var prop2 in drivers[prop]) {
                var color = drivers[prop][prop2]['truck_color'];
                maps.setColors({
                    color: {
                        current: 0,
                        polygonOptions: {
                            fillColor: color,
                            fillOpacity: 0.7,
                            strokeColor: '#2143AA',
                            strokeWeight: 2,
                            suppressUndo: true
                        }
                    }
                });
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById(id), 'click', function() {
                    maps.setColor(color);
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

It is not working so basiclly I want the loop to produce dynamically a code like this:

```
maps.setColors({
    '#00FF00': {
        current: 0,
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#00FF00',
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            strokeColor: '#2143AA',
            strokeWeight: 2,
            suppressUndo: true
        }
    },
    '#FF0000': {
        current: 0,
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            strokeColor: '#2143AA',
            strokeWeight: 2,
            suppressUndo: true
        }
    }
});
```

How can I do that please?

Thanks

Comment: in `ES2015` you can write `{[color]: {}}` Other way you should define all of them key-by-key: `o[color] = {};`

Comment: are you sure this is the correct json???

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the job:

```
var params = {};
for (var prop2 in drivers[prop]) {
    var color = drivers[prop][prop2]['truck_color'];
    params[color] = {
        current: 0,
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: color,
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            strokeColor: '#2143AA',
            strokeWeight: 2,
            suppressUndo: true
        }
    };
}
maps.setColors(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should put it like this:

```
var prove = {
                [color]: {
                    current: 0,
                    polygonOptions: {
                        fillColor: color,
                        fillOpacity: 0.7,
                        strokeColor: '#2143AA',
                        strokeWeight: 2,
                        suppressUndo: true
                    }
                }};
```

With brakets.
See console output in this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKGNbB?editors=1111

Comment: What's the output you get using [color]?

Comment: `Object {
  #00FF00: Object {
    current: 0,
    polygonOptions: Object {}
  }
}`